# How to run a json absolute path in a function

Tags: javascript, json

i have a JSON object

```
stateObj:{
    template: {
              cache:false,
              ref :"templates/pages/menu",
              searchability: true,
              path: "content.AdminFichiers.aPropos.administrateurs",
              lastUpdate: "Dernières mises à jour"
          }
}
```

i call it like this

```
updatedata (stateObj.template.path);
```

the function to update the container looks like this

```
function updatedata (dataObj){ 
       var final = "stateObj",
           nameSplit = dataObj.split("."),
           uls = document.createElement("ul");

        for(i in nameSplit) {
            final +=  '["' + nameSplit[i] +'"]'
        }  
       console.log(final);
      for(var i in final){
           console.log(stateObj["content"]["AdminFichiers"]["aPropos"]["administrateurs"]);//this shows me the object
           console.log(final);//this shows me stateObj["content"]["AdminFichiers"]["aPropos"]["administrateurs"]  but i want the object
           uls.innerHTML +=  "<li class='col-3 inline-block card aliceblue fadeIn'><div>Prenom: "+final[i]["prenom"]+"</div><div>Nom: "+final[i]["nom"]+"</div><div>Tel: "+final[i]["tel"]+"</div><div>Mail: "+final[i]["mail"]+"</div><div> Localisation: "+i+"</div></li>"
      }
         contentElement.appendChild(uls)
    }
```

here is the **console.log(final);**

```
stateObj["content"]["AdminFichiers"]["aPropos"]["administrateurs"]
```

and here is what i get at the end

[image]

why am i getting undefine everywhere?

When i do

```
for(var i in final){console.log(stateObj["content"]["AdminFichiers"]["aPropos"]["administrate‌​urs"]); }
```

it show me the result as object.

how can i run

`stateObj["content"]["AdminFichiers"]["aPropos"]["administrateurs"]`

on object

Comment: To fetch from a string you built, you'd need to use `eval()`, but there are *much* better ways. Also, don't use `for-in` on an Array in JS. It's fraught with peril. Use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** After reprashing the question you made it much clearer. You wanted a way to convert the string `"a[x][y][z]"` to the actual `Object` pointed by it.

Using eval is not recommended, what you can do is:

- start from Object `Q = a`
- then go to the next key, `Q = Q[x]` (so now actually `Q == a[x]`)
- then to the next `Q = Q[y]` (`Q == a[x][y]`)
- and so on until you reach the last key, `z` (`Q == a[x][y][z]`)

Code:

```
function updatedata (dataObj){ 
  var nameSplit = dataObj.split("."),
      uls = document.createElement("ul");

  // Start from the root object, follow each given key
  var final = stateObj;
  for(var i = 0; i < nameSplit.length; ++i) {
    var key = nameSplit[i];
    final = final[key];
  } 

  for(var i in final){
      // This next part is wrong, your final Array is an one dimensional String array
      // Accessing anything in the form of final[i][X] will not yield the result you are looking for
      // What are you trying to output?
       uls.innerHTML +=  "<li class='col-3 inline-block card aliceblue fadeIn'><div>Prenom: "+final[i]["prenom"]+"</div><div>Nom: "+final[i]["nom"]+"</div><div>Tel: "+final[i]["tel"]+"</div><div>Mail: "+final[i]["mail"]+"</div><div> Localisation: "+i+"</div></li>"
  }
     contentElement.appendChild(uls)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're trying to access an object property where there is none. Your **final[i]** will return a character in the 'i'-th position from the final string you're printed above. **final[i]** will return a character, not an object. So there's no way you'll end up with a value from something like **final[i]["prenom"]**

Answer (score 1):

Its happening because when you split the `nameSplit` in for-in loop, each letter comes each string. So, just use `toString()` function into make your function work.

Use this code :

```
function updatedata (dataObj){ 
   var final = "stateObj",
       nameSplit = dataObj.split("."),
       uls = document.createElement("ul");

   classList(uls).add("row", "text-center"); 

    for(i in nameSplit) {
        final +=  ' ["' + nameSplit[i] +'"]'
    }  
   final = final.toString().split(" ");
   console.log(final);
  for(var i in nameSplit){
       uls.innerHTML +=  "<li class='col-3 inline-block card aliceblue fadeIn'><div>Prenom: "+final[i]["prenom"]+"</div><div>Nom: "+final[i]["nom"]+"</div><div>Tel: "+final[i]["tel"]+"</div><div>Mail: "+final[i]["mail"]+"</div><div> Localisation: "+i+"</div></li>"
  }
     contentElement.appendChild(uls)
}
```

Hope it works for you :)

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v6v7oxtL/)

Comment: The `toString()` is not needed. The `final` variable is already a `String`.

Comment: @Cristy,Thinker But when i do for(var i in final){console.log(stateObj["content"]["AdminFichiers"]["aPropos"]["administrate‌​urs"]); } it show me the result as object.  please chek the update

Comment: @Tambo I think I understand your problem now, see my edit.